How to correct this script to detect OS type?
I'm trying to modify a Makefile so I can easily run my app by make run
run:
    OUTPUT=${uname -a | awk '{ print tolower($1)}'}
    bin/${OUTPUT}_${ARCH}/${APP_NAME}

Running uname -a | awk '{ print tolower($1)}' directly on terminal (I'm on macOS Monterey) gives this output:

darwin

Which I think is correct. But running the Makefile above doesn't work:

OUTPUT=
bin/_amd64/my_dummy_service
make: bin/_amd64/my_dummy_service:
No such file or directory make: *** [run] Error 1

Wonder why $OUTPUT is blank? zsh scripting isn't my forte, so any help is appreciated.
